# Split string into array, convert last number to int and subtract, replace original string with new int in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that takes an argument that looks like this: 7.0.5 or maybe 10.34.7.2

I want to take the last digit of the string, subtract 1 from it, then re-save the original string replacing the last number with the new one.  Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set tag=%1
echo %tag%

for %%a in ("%tag:.=" "%") do set "output=%%~a"
echo last number: %output%

set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ("%tag%") do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "numbers[!count!]=%%a"
    echo numbers[a]: %%a
)

for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do echo %numbers[%%a]%

set /a lastNum=%output%
echo lastNum: %lastNum%

set /a prevNum=lastNum-1
echo prevNum: %prevNum%
```

This doesn't work, obviously.  The second for loop will only print the first digit and when I get to the third for loop, it only prints `ECHO is off.`  And I haven't even gotten to replacing the string.  But if I can get the array populated, then it should be simple.

Comment: What about the following possible scenarios, `5.7.0`, `6.0.0`, `10.0.0.0`? I'm assuming you don't really want, `5.7.-1`, `6.0.-1`, `10.0.0.-1`, but more likely `5.6.9`, `5.9.9`, `9.9.9.9`, which isn't what you've described!

Comment: But then... how would we, or the script, know if it shouldn't be `5.6.09`, `5.17.23`, `09.05.16.19`? The only safe way would to compare each version string against a full listing of previous version strings.

Comment: Not a solution but just a remark on your code: `echo %numbers[%%a]%` should read `echo !numbers[%%a]!` (or even better `echo(!numbers[%%a]!`)…

Comment: You are right, the edge cases you provided are valid, however for my purposes can be ignored.  I just needed a simple script that works most of the time. It isn't part of any formal build.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it like a file name and it becomes trivial. Your last token would then be the extension, available as `%%~xa`, the part before would be the "file name", available as `%%~na`:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set tag=%~1
echo input: %tag%
set "last=%~x1"           &REM last token ("extension")
set /a last=%last:~1%-1   &REM remove the dot and subtract one
set "prevnum=%~n1.%last%" &REM reassemble "filename"."newExtension"
echo lastNum: %~1         &REM original parameter
echo prevNum: %prevNum%   &REM new calcualted value
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "tag=%1"
echo %tag%

set "last=%tag:.=" & set "out=!out!!last!." & set /A "last=%-1" & set "out=!out!!last!"

echo %out%
```

If you want to comprehend where the magic is, remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review the executed code...